# Curl of a Point Vortex Flow and its Circulation

Tags: vector-analysis, fluid-dynamics

I have the following 2D vector field $U=(u,v)=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}(y,-x)$. When taking the curl of this field it returns zero. But when I take the circulation of the field defined as $$\Gamma=\oint_C U\cdot dl$$ it returns $\Gamma=2\pi$ which implies according to Stokes theorem that $\nabla \times U\ne0$.

Is there a way I can more accurately represent $\nabla\times U$ to account for the discrepancy? Also what is the physical reasoning for $\nabla\times U=0$ despite $\Gamma=\iint_\partial\nabla\times U\cdot \hat ndS=2\pi$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing to polar coordinates, the velocity field is $\displaystyle \mathbb{u} = \frac1{r}\mathbb{e}_\theta.$  There is a singularity at $(0,0)$.

The circulation is

$$\Gamma=\oint_C U\cdot dl  = \int_0^{2\pi}\frac1{r}r \, d\theta = 2\pi$$

Stokes theorem in 2D is

$$\oint_C u\,dx + v \, dy  = \int\int_R \left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}- \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)dxdy,$$

where $R$ is the region enclosed by $C$.

This fails here because $(0,0) \in R$ and the velocity components are not continuously differentiable.

Formally we can equate the two integrals by treating the vorticity as a generalized (Dirac delta) function. This, in fact, is the model for a point vortex that generates the given velocity field:

$$\mathbb{\omega}= 2\pi \delta(\mathbb{x})\mathbb{e}_z.$$

Comment: Ok thanks I will try that. Also, I found $\Gamma=2\pi$ by using the original definition of circulation with the velocity taken around a rectangular circuit going around the origin. As you pointed out, this is likely where my problems arose.

Comment: I will expand on the answer to clarify some more. Change to polar coordinates.

Comment: This velocity field seems to be reminiscent of a point vortex flow. I was under the impression that this flow satisfied the inviscid momentum (Euler) equations. But doesn't the presence of this singularity prove otherwise? I will see if using the stream function instead gives different results in the morning.

Comment: @NWernerC456: That will not work either unless you recognize that for a point vortex, the vorticity is zero everywhere except at the origin where it is infinite  As shown above, If we use the Dirac delta function then a generalized Stokes theorem gives the correct value. Here we use $\omega = \partial_x v - \partial_y u = 2\pi \delta(\mathbb{x})$.  In this case we say $2 \pi$ is the strength of the point vortex.  Recall that for a delta function $\int \delta(x-x_0) dx  = 1$ if the region of integration includes $x_0$.

Comment: Alright, I thought I would need to use the delta function at some point I was just unsure how to do so in two dimensions. Why did you choose $\omega=2\pi\delta(x)$? Was that because the circulation including the origin returns $2\pi$?

Comment: Yes that $\mathbb{x}$ is meant to be the vector $\mathbb{x} = (x,y)$ so integration over any region in the plane including the origin gives us $2\pi$.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful and helped me understand physics much better.

Answer (score 0):

Your vector field is not defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ so Green's theorem doesn't apply.

Comment: This uses Stokes theorem which is perfectly valid in this in this instance.

Comment: Green's theorem is the common name for Stokes' theorem in 2D. Obviously it does not hold in this case - you proved that in the question!